# Using initial value of observable in subscription along with the mapped one

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming

Take a look at the following code snippet:

```
vertx.eventBus().consumer<JsonObject>(CREATEMEETING_SERVICE_ID).toObservable()
                .map { objectMapper.readValue(it.body().getJsonObject("body").encode(), Meeting::class.java) }
                .flatMap (meetingService::createMeeting)
                .subscribe(
                        { Json.encodePrettily(it) },
                        { throw it }
                )
```

I need to call *message.reply* method from the initial observable in *onNext* method of subscribe. One way of doing this is to use *Pairs* of  rather than *Meeting* alone what makes this ugly. Is there any other option to make this work not having to use *Pairs*?

I know one more way which is like this:

```
vertx.eventBus().consumer<JsonObject>(CREATEMEETING_SERVICE_ID).toObservable()
                .subscribe { 
                    message ->
                        Observable.just(objectMapper.readValue(message.body().getJsonObject("body").encode(), Meeting::class.java))
                                .flatMap(meetingService::createMeeting)
                                .subscribe(
                                        { message.reply(Json.encodePrettily(it)) },
                                        { throw it }
                                )
                }
```

But it also looks wrong.

Maybe it also explains the problem.

Comment: can you explain a bit more? what is message.reply you are talking about. What createMeeting is doing etc?

Comment: Sure, please see the second listing - should make it clear.

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by ugly here?

Comment: Looks a bit like callback hell

Comment: No, its native way of doing it. You are doing it right in your first code example.

Comment: Yeah except in the first example I'm not exactly doing what I should do - I'd like to do "message.reply(Json.encodePrettily(it))" rather than "Json.encodePrettily(it)" alone.

Comment: So what is holding u back from doing it? Is that also a network call?